# Why does storing a reference to a function then calling the function cause 'this' to have a context of window?

Tags: javascript

I am reading a tutorial at so I can understand _.bind and _bindAll: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html

The website has the following code

```
function Developer(skill) {
  this.skill = skill;
  this.says = function(){
    alert(this.skill + ' rocks!');
  }
}
var john = new Developer('Ruby');
john.says(); //Ruby rocks!
```

vs

```
function Developer(skill) {
  this.skill = skill;
  this.says = function(){
    alert(this.skill + ' rocks!');
  }
}
var john = new Developer('Ruby');
var func = john.says;
func();// undefined rocks!
```

Why does storing a reference to a function then calling the function cause this to have a context of window?

Comment: because the variable `func`'s context is the `window` object, not `john`. You should be doing `var func = john.says.bind(john);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute

```
a.b();
```

then `a` is the context of execution of `b` (`this` inside `b`) unless `b` is a bound function.

If you don't have `a`, that is if you have

```
b();
```

then it's the same as

```
window.b();
```

so `window` is the context of execution of `b`.

Note also that

```
a.b();
```

is the same as

```
b.call(a);
```

and

```
b();
```

is the same as

```
b.call(); // call replaces its first argument by the global object if it's null or undefined
```

If you want to bind the context, then you can do (on modern browsers)

```
var func = john.says.bind(john);
func();
```

or (more classically) use a closure :

```
var func = function(){john.says()};
func();
```

Comment: I'm sure somebody had a reason to downvote me. Might I be enlightened ?

Comment: This really make it clearer to me. Thanks. Basically what you are saying is the context is the object before the "dot" if there is no "dot" it is window

Answer (score 2):

#### Because the "this" keyword is bound at *call* time, not *definition* time.

When you call `john.says()` it's like doing `john.says.apply(john)`.

When you call `func()` it's like doing `func.apply()`.

Yehuda Katz has a great explanation of "[JavaScript function invocation and `this`](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/)".